# Display large number in compact notation in i18n compatible way (ex: display 122025999 as 122M or 1.2億) across browsers

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization, cross-browser, number-formatting

Need a cross browser compatible way to display compact notation for large numbers, very similar to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat with the notation: 'compact' parameters, currently in experiment mode. Or the chrome v8: https://v8.dev/features/intl-numberformat#notation

```
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en', {
    notation: 'compact',
  });
```

I want to use these compact notation number formatters with locale support, but they are not yet cross browser compatible.

Does anyone have a solution similar to this chrome implementation that also works in firefox, safari, etc.?

Comment: Have you found a good substitute?

Comment: @Flink I haven't found one yet :(

Comment: yea i made a custom implementation for now...

Comment: how did you do your custom implementation? I want to display compact notation for large numbers in all browsers too. thanks

Comment: You could check out https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-numbers-modern/tree/master/main for examples of patterns used to do this kind of formatting for the locales you need to support. Make your own file of hardcoded objects for each locale, containing formatting patterns for different types of numbers (percentages, currencies, negative currencies, etc.) and for different grouping numbers (1K, 1M, 1B, 1万, etc.). Detect the locale and load up the right patterns dynamically. Write your own code to interpret the patterns and format the numbers accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

> It’s actually quite simple, here’s Berezza’s method for abbreviating
> numerals ( Provides a lot more options than compact notation parameter );

```
> local Suffixes =
> {"k","M","B","T","qd","Qn","sx","Sp","O","N","de","Ud","DD","tdD","qdD","QnD","sxD","SpD","OcD","NvD","Vgn","UVg","DVg","TVg","qtV","QnV","SeV","SPG","OVG","NVG","TGN","UTG","DTG","tsTG","qtTG","QnTG","ssTG","SpTG","OcTG","NoTG","QdDR","uQDR","dQDR","tQDR","qdQDR","QnQDR","sxQDR","SpQDR","OQDDr","NQDDr","qQGNT","uQGNT","dQGNT","tQGNT","qdQGNT","QnQGNT","sxQGNT","SpQGNT",
> "OQQGNT","NQQGNT","SXGNTL"}                                           
> 
> 
> function Convert(Input)   local Negative = Input < 0  Input =
> math.abs(Input)
> 
>   local Paired = false    for i,v in pairs(Suffixes) do       if not (Input
> >= 10^(3*i)) then             Input = Input / 10^(3*(i-1))            local isComplex = (string.find(tostring(Input),".") and string.sub(tostring(Input),4,4)
> ~= ".")           Input = string.sub(tostring(Input),1,(isComplex and 4) or
> 3) .. (Suffixes[i-1] or "")           Paired = true           break;      end     end     if
> not Paired then       local Rounded = math.floor(Input)       Input =
> tostring(Rounded)     end     if Negative then        return "-"..Input   end
>   return Input -- returns 1.0k for example end Now to add commas to a
```

> numeral , or to abbreviate it that style is a different function;

```
> function AbbreviateNumeral(numeral)   if numeral then         local
> left,num,right = string.match(numeral,'^([^%d]*%d)(%d*)(.-)$')
>       return left..(num:reverse():gsub('(%d%d%d)','%1,'):reverse())..right
```

> -- returns for example 1,000, it gets every 3 zeros and adds a  comma     end end All you have to do is call one of these functions and it’ll
> return a number abbreviated!

Use Kensizo suggested.
https://devforum.roblox.com/t/how-can-i-turn-a-number-to-a-shorter-number-i-dont-know-how-to-explain-click-to-understand-3/649496/3

> In my game that is upcoming, Samurai Legends, it’s easier for players to understand Berezza’s conversion it seems to be, but whichever you prefer and think is cleaner is the one you should go with!

Unlike your method

> it can also support negative numerals, which is pretty cool.

Comment: This question is specifically asking about locale aware symbols for an internationalized / localized codebase. The solution posted is essentially hard coding the English compact notation and does not include any other language symbols or locale aware formatting for different number systems, so definitely does not answer the question asked.

Comment: John, 
please reformat your code example. Currently, it is totally illegible!